# Using Select and Join in compare date entered by user

Tags: php, mysql

$sql = "SELECT * FROM invoices JOIN suppliers ON (suppliers.supplier_id = invoices.supplier_id) WHERE $date >= invoices.due_date";

My sql statement is not executing, I cant seem to find the problem, can someone correct it for me.

NB. '$date' variable is currently represented as a timestamp.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `phpmyadmin` and post `php` code? Where are you trying to execute that code? In `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: echo $sql. My guess is that you're missing inverted commas around $date

Comment: My database is hosted on PHPMYADMIN on xxamp but i am executing this statement from a php script which then moves on to display data but something is wrong with mysql statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but somehow it is still not returning any records despite  $date being greater than invoices.due_date.

Comment: AS @Strawberry said, echo $sql and post the resulting sql statement. Looks like it doesn't have anything to do with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert your `$date` to the representation of your `due_date` column.

As your column is probably in the DATE or DATETIME format, you should use the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function (ref. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)), e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM invoices JOIN suppliers ON (suppliers.supplier_id = invoices.supplier_id) WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME( $date ) >= invoices.due_date";
```

Alternatively, you can do the conversion in PHP, using e.g. `$date = date( DATE_ISO8601, $date )`, before doing your query.